# Hide DIV when page loads based on select field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following script that hides/shows 2 div's based on the contents of a select ID's value when it's changed. This works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#ue_package").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "Featured") {
                    $(".image_container").hide();
                    $(".image_container_featured").show();              
                } else if ($(this).val() == "Standard") { 
                    $(".image_container").show();
                    $(".image_container_featured").hide();              
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

What I'm trying to do is perform this same action, except not only on CHANGE, but when the page loads as well. So when I enter the page, if FEATURED is value then correct DIV will already be hidden and shown.

I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
                $("#ue_package").change(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == "Featured") {
                        $(".image_container").hide();
                        $(".image_container_featured").show();              
                    } else if ($(this).val() == "Standard") { 
                        $(".image_container").show();
                        $(".image_container_featured").hide();              
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: this may not answer to your question. have a class .hide{display:none}; and toggle it . instead of .show() and .hide(). it will repaint every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the toogling as a function. Note replace $(this) with the element id selector and call that function in both the onchange and body onload like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   showHide();
   $("#ue_package").change(function () {
        showHide();
   });
});


function showHide() {
    if ($('#ue_package').val() == "Featured") {
        $(".image_container").hide();
        $(".image_container_featured").show();              
    } else if ($('#ue_package').val() == "Standard") { 
        $(".image_container").show();
        $(".image_container_featured").hide();              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke/trigger the `change` function in your `document.ready` event handler function after binding the `change` event to the same textbox.

```
$("#ue_package").change();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ($("#ue_package").val() == "Featured") {
            $(".image_container").hide();
            $(".image_container_featured").show();              
        } else if ($("#ue_package").val() == "Standard") { 
                $(".image_container").show();
                $(".image_container_featured").hide();              
        }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not worked buz change event is fires when, any action perform.

so there is two options  One:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
 showHidediv();
            $("#ue_package").change(function () {
               showHidediv();
        });

function showHidediv()
     {
 if ($("#ue_package").val() == "Featured") {
                    $(".image_container").hide();
                    $(".image_container_featured").show();              
                } else if ($("#ue_package").val() == "Standard") { 
                    $(".image_container").show();
                    $(".image_container_featured").hide();              
                }
 }
    </script>
```

second method:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       $("#ue_package").change();


 $("#ue_package").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "Featured") {
                    $(".image_container").hide();
                    $(".image_container_featured").show();              
                } else if ($(this).val() == "Standard") { 
                    $(".image_container").show();
                    $(".image_container_featured").hide();              
                }
            });
 });
```

[For more about change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest this, as i changed a little the logic, 
 i put the images into divs and i play with the active class.

**into javascript:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            if ($("#ue_package").val() == "Featured") {
                $('.container:eq(0)').addClass('active');
            $('.container:eq(1)').removeClass('active');
        } else if ($("#ue_package").val() == "Standard") { 
                $('.container:eq(0)').removeClass('active');
                    $('.container:eq(1)').addClass('active');
        }
}
```

**into css:**

```
.container{
  display:none
}

.container.active{
  display:block;
}
```

**into html:**

```
<div class="container">
  <img class='image_container' src="something"/>1
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img class='image_container' src="something"/>2
</div>
```

hope helps good luck.